# How to change GET in url from html form?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, friendly-url

Default url view looks like this: https://example.com/user.php?page=history
I change it with **.htaccess** to: https://example.com/user/history/
Problem in navigation bar which I made with radio type form. And it gives me: https://example.com/user/history/?page=history
How to change it? Help pls.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)$ /user.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/$ /user.php?p=$1
```

```
<form name='page' id='page'>
     <input id="history" type="radio" name="page" <?php if ($p == 'history') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> onChange="autoSubmit();" value="history" >
     <label for="history">Історія замовлень</label>

     <input id="settings" type="radio" name="page" <?php if ($p == 'settings') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?>onChange="autoSubmit();" value="settings">
     <label for="settings">Налаштування</label>
</form>
```

```
<script>
  function autoSubmit(){
    var formObject=document.forms['page'];
    formObject.submit();}
</script>
```

```
<?php
$p="";
if(isset($_GET["page"])){
    $p=$_GET["page"];
}
?>
```

Radio type menu needs to be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Please try following rules as per shown samples in comments.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ user.php?page=$1 [L]
```

---

---

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess Rules file, make sure your php file(s) and htaccess are in same folder. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Doing external rewrite to friendly url here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.*)/?\?page=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [QSD,R=301,L,NE]
##Doing internal rewrite to php files here.
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ user.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```